# Basic Save form data the Angular way

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to figure out the "correct" way to get and set form data using Angular. (By "correct" I mean one that supports scalability to larger apps, where controllers aren't overly simple, with shortcut references, as they are in most demos.) When I look though the examples, the seem so basic (such as no controllerAs specifier) that I can't figure out what's pointing at what.

Anyway, I'm expecting that there is an object somewhere in my viewmodel, accessible by the controller, that contains the data in its named fields, suitable for PUTing to the api - and **doesn't** contain all the cruft that is associated with the actual form and field objects:

To-wit: this is what settingsVm.settingsForm contains:

```
$dirty:true
$error:{}
$invalid:false
$name:"settingsVm.settingsForm"
$pristine:false
$submitted:true
$valid:true
Email:"asdsa@asdsad.com"
Id:{$validators: {}, $asyncValidators: {}, $parsers: [], $formatters: [], $viewChangeListeners: [],…}
$asyncValidators:{}
$dirty:false
$error:{}
$formatters:[]
$invalid:false
$name:"Id"
$options:null
$parsers:[]
$pristine:true
$touched:false
$untouched:true
$valid:true
$validators:{}
$viewChangeListeners:[]
StreetDirection:""
StreetName:"asdasdsadsada"
StreetNumber:"34"
Suite:""
```

Here is my form, with just a couple of fields:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" ng-model="settingsVm.settings.Id" />

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Email" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label text-right"> Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group-med" maxlength="50" name="Email" ng-model="settingsVm.settingsForm.Email" required />
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="settingsVm.settingsForm.Email.$invalid && settingsVm.settingsForm.Email.$touched || settingsVm.settingsForm.submitted">
                    <span ng-show="settingsVm.settingsForm.Email.$error.required"> Email is required.</span >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="StreetName" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label text-right"> Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group-med" maxlength="50" name="Email" ng-model="settingsVm.settingsForm.StreetName" required />
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="settingsVm.settingsForm.StreetName.$invalid && settingsVm.settingsForm.StreetName.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
                    <span ng-show="settingsVm.settingsForm.StreetName.$error.required">Street Name is required.</span >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
</form>
```

Am I using the ng-model correctly? And am I using the $error correctly?

Should my **model** be a distinct object from my **form**? Maybe my model should point at settingsVm.settingsData instead of settingsVm.settingsForm.

Here is my submit:

```
    vm.submit = function (isValid) {
        vm.submitted = true;

        if (isValid) {
            settingsService.putSettings(vm.settingsForm);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Having same issue now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you after 3 months, but I figured it out, please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Yes your statement is right, you actually need to separate form validation and input fields.

I assume when you are using field validation angular actually uses input field names not the ng-Model values. So this works for me

```js
var myapp = angular.module("taskApp", [])
  .controller("taskCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.form = {};

    $scope.makeTask = function(data) {
      console.dir(data);

    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-App="taskApp" ng-controller="taskCtrl">
  <form name="TaskForm" novalidate ">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="Name " ng-required="true " class="form-control " ng-model="form.Name " />
    <span ng-show="TaskForm.Name.$invalid && TaskForm.Name.$dirty ">The name is required</span>
  </div>
  <button ng-Click="makeTask(form) " type="submit ">Add</button>

</form>

<div id="output ">OUTPUT</div>
```